# How to deploy Flask application with Nginx and uWSGI?

Tags: nginx, flask

I am deploying Flask application with Nginx and uWSGI for first time. Nginx will listen to port 8000 and WSGI will listen to 8081. I got errors while running the assignment.

Problem statement: Deploy a simple flask application with nginx and uwsgi.

Commands for configuring nginx server as per Problem statement:

1. sudo vi /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
2. The I was asked to include /projects/challenge/deploy.config in Virtual Host configs.
3. sudo service nginx restart

For the code, this is what I did: wsgi.py

```
# Put your code here
from .api import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

deploy.conf

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost:8081;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8081;
    }

    location /Hello {
        alias /project/challenges/api.py;
    }
}
```

api.py

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response


app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "Thisisyoursecret"


# Create a simple endpoint /Hello with return message "Welcome to your flask application"

@app.route('/Hello')
def hello():
  res=make_response("Welcome to your flask application")
  return res
```

As per instruction in the question, I included deploy.conf in Virtual Host Configs of nginx.conf file as follows:

```
http{
   ...
        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
        include /projects/challenge/deploy.conf;
}
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
socket=127.0.0.1:8081
wsgi-file=wsgi.py
```

The test code given in the question for testing my code is:

```
import os

import pytest
import requests
from .api import app



class Test_API:

client = app.test_client()

def test_hello_from_app(self): #Failed
    url = "/Hello"
    response = self.client.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.data == b'Welcome to your flask application'
        
def test_hello_from_app_on_port(self):   #Failed
    url = "http://localhost:8081/Hello"
    response = requests.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.text == 'Welcome to your flask application'

def test_hello_from_nginx_server(self):  #Failed
    url = "http://localhost:8000/Hello"
    response = requests.get(url)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.text == 'Welcome to your flask application'    


def test_conf_file_contents(self):
    with open('deploy.conf', 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()
        assert "location /Hello" in content
        assert "server localhost:8081" in content  # Assertion error here
        assert "listen 8000" in content
```

The error is:

```
            assert "location /Hello" in content
>           assert "server localhost:8081" in content
E           AssertionError: assert 'server localhost:8081' in 'server {\n    listen 8000;\n    server_name localhost:8081;\n\n    location / {\n        include uwsgi_params;\n        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8081;\n    }\n\n    location /Hello {\n        alias /project/challenges/api.py;\n    }\n}'

tests.py:34: AssertionError
======================================= warnings summary =======================================
/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/junitxml.py:417
  /home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/_pytest/junitxml.py:417: PytestDeprecationWarning: The 'junit_family' default value will change to 'xunit2' in pytest 6.0.
  Add 'junit_family=xunit1' to your pytest.ini file to keep the current format in future versions of pytest and silence this warning.
    _issue_warning_captured(deprecated.JUNIT_XML_DEFAULT_FAMILY, config.hook, 2)

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
----------------------- generated xml file: /projects/challenge/unit.xml -----------------------
=================================== short test summary info ====================================
FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_hello_from_app - assert 500 == 200
FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_hello_from_app_on_port - assert 500 == 200
FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_hello_from_nginx_server - assert 404 == 200
FAILED tests.py::Test_API::test_conf_file_contents - AssertionError: assert 'server localhost...
================================= 4 failed, 1 warning in 0.31s =================================
```

Nginx is running fine.
I went through Google and Youtube but could not figure out what to fix. No solution worked. I am a beginner in this field. I suspect the deploy.conf or wsgi file but I have no clue how to fix the issue.

Kindly suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `;` on `nginx.conf`

`include /projects/challenge/deploy.conf`

should be

`include /projects/challenge/deploy.conf;`

To prevent this in future, always use `nginx -t` to validate your config files.

Comment: I have added the semicolons. nginx is running now. But I ran into errors while running the test case. I am editing my question accordingly.

Comment: Your assertion is wrong. `server_name localhost:8081;` this is the value in your `deploy.conf` file, not `server localhost:8081`.

Comment: The test program along with the assertions was provided with the question itself for checking my code. I did not write the assertions.